How to Match Compression Format for Specific Compressed Data?
I'm trying to decompress and recompress a specific piece of compressed data in Python to reproduce the original compressed output. However, I can't achieve a match with zlib, and I'm unsure what compression method or parameters were used for the original compressed data.
Here is the code I'm using:
import zlib

original_compress = '78010dc2390a80400c05d052b4d4ce4a3c8024933fdb719259c046c1c2f32bbc696ba098cd92b23242ed66625db568498d106d5e22e0202e4b622f082c24eba0577deeb3eee34bfe20fa7df036131b0000f53a00000000'

print('original_compress:', original_compress)

# Decompress the data
decompress = zlib.decompress(bytes.fromhex(original_compress))
print('decompress:', decompress.hex())

# Recompress the data
again_compress = zlib.compress(decompress)
print('again_compress:', again_compress.hex())

# Compare the results
if original_compress == again_compress.hex():
    print('Matched')
else:
    print('NotMatched')

Issue:
Decompression works fine with zlib, so I assume it's a zlib-compatible format.
However, recompression does not produce a byte-for-byte match with the original data.
Observations:
The original compressed data begins with 78 01, which suggests it's using a zlib header (possibly DEFLATE with no compression).
The decompressed data is valid, and I can confirm the integrity of the decompression.
Questions:
How can I reproduce the exact original compressed output? Are there specific parameters or flags I need to use with zlib?
Could the original data use a custom or non-standard compression implementation? If so, how can I identify it?
Are there any tools or libraries (beyond zlib) that can help me reverse-engineer the compression format used?
import ctypes

# Load the compiled miniz DLL for Windows
miniz = ctypes.CDLL("C:/Users/neatbox/miniz/miniz.dll")

# Define function signatures for decompression and compression
miniz.mz_compress2.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ulong), ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_ulong, ctypes.c_int]
miniz.mz_compress2.restype = ctypes.c_int

miniz.mz_uncompress.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ulong), ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_ulong]
miniz.mz_uncompress.restype = ctypes.c_int

# Decompress using miniz
def decompress_miniz(data):
    source = ctypes.create_string_buffer(data)
    source_len = len(data)
    dest_len = ctypes.c_ulong(source_len * 4)  # Allocate more space for decompressed data
    dest = ctypes.create_string_buffer(dest_len.value)

    result = miniz.mz_uncompress(dest, ctypes.byref(dest_len), source, source_len)
    if result != 0:
        raise RuntimeError("Decompression failed")
    return dest.raw[:dest_len.value]

# Compress using miniz with the default compression level
def compress_miniz(data, level=1):
    source = ctypes.create_string_buffer(data)
    source_len = len(data)
    dest_len = ctypes.c_ulong(source_len * 2)  # Allocate more space for compressed data
    dest = ctypes.create_string_buffer(dest_len.value)

    result = miniz.mz_compress2(dest, ctypes.byref(dest_len), source, source_len, level)
    if result != 0:
        raise RuntimeError("Compression failed")
    return dest.raw[:dest_len.value]

# Original compressed data
original_compress = bytes.fromhex(
    '78010dc2390a80400c05d052b4d4ce4a3c8024933fdb719259c046c1c2f32bbc696ba098cd92b23242ed66625db568498d106d5e22e0202e4b622f082c24eba0577deeb3eee34bfe20fa7df036131b0000f53a00000000'
)

print(f"Original Compressed Data (hex): {original_compress.hex()}")
print(f"Original Compressed Length: {len(original_compress)} bytes")

# Step 1: Decompress
try:
    decompressed = decompress_miniz(original_compress)
    print(f"Decompressed Data (hex): {decompressed.hex()}")
    print(f"Decompressed Length: {len(decompressed)} bytes")
except RuntimeError as e:
    print(f"Decompression failed: {e}")
    exit()

# Step 2: Recompress
try:
    #print(f"{compress_miniz(decompressed)} aaa")
    recompressed = compress_miniz(decompressed)
    print(f"Recompressed Data (hex): {recompressed.hex()}")
    print(f"Recompressed Length: {len(recompressed)} bytes")

    # Step 3: Check if recompressed matches the original
    if recompressed == original_compress:
        print("Matched")
    else:
        print("NotMatched")
except RuntimeError as e:
    print(f"Compression failed: {e}")


It would be helpful to see the decompressed string and the recompressed one displayed in full. They don't look to be too long. There are quite a few encoding compression tricks which decoders can all decode but only the better encoders bother to do. What were the respective lengths of the two compressed strings?

@MartinBrown, It seems the issue might be related to subtle encoding compression tricks, as you pointed out. Both the decompressed and recompressed strings appear to retain the same data integrity, but the recompressed string is not matching byte-for-byte with the original.
Do you have any insights into specific compression tricks or encoder settings that might influence this behavior? Any advice or direction would be greeeatly appreciated! thx

Why do you want to reproduce the compressed data? The new compressed data decompresses correctly to the original data, so there is no problem.

There are eight extraneous bytes after the zlib stream in original_compress. No zlib compressor will ever produce those.
Once you get rid of those, miniz will replicate the compressed data using compression level 1.

Thank you! Do you suggest stripping those extra bytes manually or could they indicate metadata from a specific tool like miniz? Any guidance is appreciated!
https://github.com/richgel999/miniz

updated, is that considered a match? how about the last digits?

I have no idea what put those bytes there, or why. You would need to go back to where you got that from to do that detective work. My understanding is that miniz uses the same formats as zlib, so those eight bytes would be extraneous to miniz as well.
